# could the POJO used for Gson reused for the class used with Room

Tags: android, android-room, gson

when using Gson it has POJO created for parsing/serializing the json data result from the remote service. It may have some Gson's annotation

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName(“_id”)
    @Expose
    public String id;
    @SerializedName(“_name”)
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName(“_lastName”)
    @Expose
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName(“_age”)
    @Expose
    public Integer age;
}
```

but for the class using with Room, it may have its own annotation:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity
public class User {
    public @PrimaryKey String id;
    public String name;
    public String lastName;
    public int age;
}
```

could these two be combined into one with all of the annotation from two libs (if there is annotation clash (hope not), it would have to be resolved with long package names)?

Comment: I would not expect either library's annotations to interfere with the other library's annotations.

Comment: I don't think you'll have any problems with this. Each framework handles it's own annotation classes and processes the metadata inside.

Comment: I don't expect them to clash. Have you tried?

Answer (score 13):

yes you can make one single pojo class for room and gson.
and when request to server and if any data not be send in server that time used **transient** keyword and if you want not insert any field table used 
**@Ignore**.

used below code for gson and room..

```
 @Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("_id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    public long userId;
    @SerializedName("_fName")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String name;

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It will work but may result in some issues in the future and is therefore not recommended for a clean software design. See this talk about it: [Marko Miloš: Clean architecture on Android](https://youtu.be/3Mq5newPdck?t=1466)

As pointed out you should use different entities for your db and webresults/json and transform between them.

Comment: What does he recommend exactly? Should we duplicate the pojo class?

Comment: He basically says, as they work on different layers, clear architecture suggests to use different classes for each of the cases