# Why does the author add @field:SerializedName annotation to a field in Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm learning Room with a sample code at https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging

The Code A is to defind a `@Entity` of a table, you can see *[it](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelabs/paging/model/Repo.kt)*.

Normally it add the `@ColumnInfo` annotation to a field, such as  `@ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?, ...` .

Why does the author add `@field:SerializedName` annotation to a field in Room database?

**Code A**

```
@Entity(tableName = "repos")
data class Repo(
    @PrimaryKey @field:SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
    @field:SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @field:SerializedName("full_name") val fullName: String,
    @field:SerializedName("description") val description: String?,
    @field:SerializedName("html_url") val url: String,
    @field:SerializedName("stargazers_count") val stars: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("forks_count") val forks: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("language") val language: String?
)
```

Comment: because he didnt implemented Serializable in his entity usermodel class. To avoid implement like: data class Repo implements Serializable.

Comment: I sincerely hope this link helps you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713643/could-the-pojo-used-for-gson-reused-for-the-class-used-with-room

Answer (score 8):

The `@SerializedName` annotation is part of *Gson* and is used to define the names of these properties in *Json*.

The `@ColumnInfo` annotation is part of *Room* and is used to define the column names of these properties in *SQLite*.

If neither of these annotation is defined, the property/field name is used as a name for the *Json* property or column.

> Why does the author add @field:SerializedName annotation to a field in Room database?

Because the *Room* entity is reused as a *Gson* DTO.